# Is mysqli extension enabled in this php configuration?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've a website designed in php with mysqli (mysql - improved) extension. The phpinfo() page shows this:

> ./configure --disable-fileinfo --disable-phar --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-ftp --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-libxml --enable-magic-quotes --enable-mbstring --enable-pdo=shared --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-wddx --enable-zend-multibyte --enable-zip --prefix=/usr --with-bz2 --with-curl=/opt/curlssl/ --with-curlwrappers --with-freetype-dir=/usr --with-gd --with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/ --with-imap-ssl=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr --with-kerberos --with-libdir=lib64 --with-libexpat-dir=/usr --with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2 --with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/ --with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/ --with-mysql=/usr --with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config --with-openssl=/usr --with-openssl-dir=/usr --with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre --with-pdo-mysql=shared --with-pdo-sqlite=shared --with-pic --with-png-dir=/usr --with-pspell --with-sqlite=shared --with-tidy=/opt/tidy/ --with-xmlrpc --with-xpm-dir=/usr --with-xsl=/opt/xslt/ --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr

Does this mean that mysqli extension is enabled in this configuration?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Should the `mysqli` extension be enabled then on the very same `phpinfo` page a "**MysqlI Support | enabled**" table header should appear. Look for that:

[image]

---

If you want to find out in a script, look for a function specific for mysqli like [`mysqli_connect()`](http://www.php.net/function.mysqli-connect) and than check if it exists:

```
var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));
```

If this outputs FALSE, then it does not exists and it's highly likely that you can not use the module.

Comment: yes, there is a section labeled "mysqli", just like the screenprint of the table you have provided. So this does mean that I can safely migrate my scripts over to this particular webhost, and that the mysqli functions will work fine, right?

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It means it was compiled with mysqli support. Whether the module is enabled or not is another question.

Comment: cartwright - 
Please help me understand (i am a total newbie here).. What I had pasted in my original question was the "Configure Command" section of the phpinfo() page of my proposed WEBHOST. If i migrate my php scripts (which have mysqli commands) to this particular webhost, will it work fine?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have already have a phpinfo() result, then search for the word "mysqli". You should see a section outlining all the details your your mysqli module.

Comment: What I just described was provided as a screenshot by @maria, just fyi.

Comment: yes, @john cartwright. i see a section for both mysql and mysqli in the phpinfo() page. 

Another doubt, I read somewhere that in the case of a shared hosting service, only one of them - either mysqli or mysql - will be enabled (or active). But this phpinfo page of mine shows both the sections. 

Am i messing up the fundamentals here, or is the webhost actually showing me a dedicated server phpinfo page?

Comment: It is perfectly fine having MySQL and MySQLi both enabled (on a shared host or a dedicated). I would assume what you have read may be the case on some shared environments to free up resources, but there is nothing stopping you from having 2, 3, 100, etc databases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux without the `phpinfo()` access, you can run the following on the terminal to validate if `mysqli` is enabled:

```bash
php -m | grep mysqli
```