# Error connecting to MYSQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an assignment that requires me to create a form that sends info to a database.
I am having issues connecting to the server.

I have tried using mysql_connect and mysqli_connect and neither work.

mysql_connect error:
Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection timed out

mysqli_connect error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

```
                    $connect=mysql_connect("server.com","username","password","database")
                    or die("Failed to connect to server");
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO client (title,fname,lname,organization,email,phone,tshirt) VALUES ($title,$fname,$lname,$org,$email,$phone,$tshirt)");

                    $tabledata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client");
                    echo "<table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Organization</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>TShirt</th>
                    </tr>";
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tabledata)){
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['title']  . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['fname']  . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['lname']  . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['org']    . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['email']  . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['phone']  . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['tshirt'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    mysql_close($connect);
```

Info from PHP INFO

mysql

MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Client API version  mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026 - $Id: e707c415db32080b3752b232487a435ee0372157 $

PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers sqlite

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.7.7.1

sqlite3

SQLite3 support enabled
SQLite3 module version  0.7
SQLite Library  3.7.7.1

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir   no value    no value

Comment: Is it a requirement to use the crappy old `mysql_query` interface?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure mysql is running, and if it already is, then I would try installing the mysql extension for your php environment anyhow, just to make sure:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql libapache2-mod-auth-mysql
```

Also, you would want to use `mysqli_*`, not `mysql_*`

After you attempt installing, just restart apache from there.

Comment: I do not have admin privileges on this server. I'm 99% sure it is already installed.

Comment: I got this error:
The program 'apt-get' can be found in the following package:
  * apt [ path: /usr/bin/apt-get, repository: zypp (openSUSE_11.1-0) ]

I couldn't find apt-get though

Comment: I happened to have the exact same issue once about a year ago, and this was what fixed it. See if you can get someone with root/sudo privileges to run that :)  EDIT: What distro is this?

Comment: Am I able to check if mysql is running?

Comment: Try running the command `/etc/init.d/mysql status` (or on redhat) `/etc/init.d/mysqld status`

Comment: My etc directory only has one file: pear.conf

Comment: Whoever manages the box you use, have them install mysql, and the extensions for it for php.

Comment: I believe it is installed because I am able to create tables and stuff using: mysql -h db-mysql -u username -p

Comment: Server version: 5.0.24-standard-log MySQL Community Edition - Standard (GPL)

Answer (score 0):

please use **[PDO::__construct()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)** or **[mysqli_connect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)** but in your question

try :

```
$connect=mysql_connect("server.com","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");
```

Comment: Same issue... connection timeout

Answer (score 0):

First, are you connecting locally or externally to your DB? If you're connecting locally your parameters for `mysql_connect();` would be as follows 
`mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');`

Then:

```
mysql_select_db('your_db')
```

Comment: Considering it isn't killing the connection due to incorrect info (and instead an undefined function), I would say it's a different issue.

Comment: If he's connecting externally that may be the issue he is having, he'd need to check whether his site allows external IP's

Comment: `mysql_connect` simply returns false on failure, it doesn't magically undefine itself...

Answer (score 0):

Is "server.com" this the real thing you're trying to connect to? Are you connecting to mysql on the local machine or is it external? Try a telnet from the php server:

```
telnet <remote db name/IP> 3306
```

If that fails, you have a network/firewall problem. Or the DB is is not listening on that port or on the network entirely. Do a netstat on the remote DB to confirm:
Linux

```
netstat -an | grep LISTENING
```

You should see :3306 if it's listening on the default port.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have enabled mysqli.dll in php ini file

with

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

if it isn't enable it in php.ini file `//remove ';'` from dll name

for [more info to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285141/is-mysqli-extension-enabled-in-this-php-configuration)