# How can my PHP program determine if it should use mySQLi or the older mySQL libary?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My development environment uses mySQLi but the hosting service that my software will run on doesn't and uses the older, deprecated mySQL libraries. I would like to build my app so that it can run either place. I'll worry about managing that in my code but first I need to know if there's a programatic way to determine which functions I should use.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285141/is-mysqli-extension-enabled-in-this-php-configuration

Comment: Sounds like you need to get a new host.

Comment: You can use `extension_loaded` to check, then I'd suggest having both your customized MySQL and MySQLi functions in seperate classes. E.g. `$yourdb->query('SQL');` - then you can easily switch between classes in a config file or something (assuming they both accept the same structure and return the same structure). Or you can use `extension_loaded` to fall back to MySQL if MySQLi isn't loaded. Manual: http://www.php.net/extension_loaded

Comment: mysqli has been around since php5 which came out in 2004. If you have a host that doesn't support mysqli, then they probably don't update/upgrade their system at all. Meaning you shouldn't trust anything on their servers. I'm *not* saying they need to be cutting edge, but maybe within this decade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can simply check

```
if(function_exists('mysqli_connect')){
   //Then do code
}else{
  //write code
}
```