# Failed with mysqli_connect() Call to undefined function

Tags: php, mysqli

## This is the error I get...

> Failed with *mysqli_connect()*

and also with *new mysqli*
If I put this line in comment "$conn = mysqli_connect..." I don't get the error since it doesn't try to connect to the DB.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Classes\Connection\mysqli_connect() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ControlePM\Classes\Connection\DBConnect.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\ControlePM\index.php(22): Classes\Connection\DBConnect->connect() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ControlePM\Classes\Connection\DBConnect.php on line 21
```

### This is my connection code

I tried with **new mysqli** same error.

```
<?php
    namespace Classes\Connection;
    class DBConnect
    {
    var $host;
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $database;
    public $dbc;
    public $connInfo=FALSE;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->host = 'localhost:3306';
        $this->username = 'root';
        $this->password = 'MyPassWord';
        $this->database = 'MyDB';
    }
    public function connect()
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->database); 

    if (! $conn) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
    echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;
    mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

---

### Index.php

```
<?php 
require_once ('Classes/Connection/DBConnect.php'); 
$conn = new DBConnect();
$conn->connect();

if (! $conn->connInfo){
    $result = "Connection failed";
}
else $result = "Connection Succes";
?>
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the mysqli extension from your PHP build.

Comment: @Devon The error quite clearly shows that PHP is looking for `mysqli_connect()` in the wrong namespace per `...undefined function Classes\Connection\mysqli_connect() in...`. I am not saying that your suggestion is not valid but it has yet to be proven.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, PHP will always show the current namespace if the function is undefined (3v4l.org/XbpVd) and the function is undefined because the extension is missing. You don't need to namespace global functions, only if you've defined a local function of the same name.

Comment: Thanks Devon, My mysqli was missing from the PHP build.

Comment: One of those absolutely misleading questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mysqli was missing from the PHP build

In the PHP.ini file "extension=mysqli" was commented

Answer (score 1):

You are using a namespace therefore you'll need to specify that it look for `mysqli` in the global namespace `new \mysqli([...])` otherwise PHP will try and look for `mysqli` in your current namespace (the one specified in your class).

Secondly, you could explicitly 'import' it via the [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) statement.

Thirdly, a useful way to check if the mysqli extension is installed is by executing the following `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));`, courtesy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6285262/2263631) answer.

Comment: Sorry I omitted to mention that ine my index.php file I am importing
    use Classes\Connection\DBConnect; 
Also mysqli is part of the PHP Language Library

Comment: @David read this answer again, and then do it, because this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

for me it was because the way passwords are authenticated with `caching_sha2_password` in MySQL 8.
PHP 7 doesn't support this apparently.
But in MySQL 8 you can still store your passwords as `mysql_native_password`

Try this:

```
ALTER USER myusername IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';
```